# WEXITSTATUS returns 1 (in parent) , although child return 0

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am using the following code in order to run some commands using parent/child:

```
int nStatus = 0;
int nRet = 0;
pid_t pid = -1;

char *envp[] =
    {
        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/tmp",
        0
    };



if(pnChildExitStatus == NULL || pcBuf == NULL)
{
    nRet = -EINVAL;
    goto returnHandler;
}
*pnChildExitStatus = 0;
pid = fork();
switch(pid)
{
    case -1:
        nRet = -errno;                           //can't fork
        break;
    case 0: //child
        nRet = execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c", pcBuf, envp,NULL);
        if (-1 == nRet) {
            nRet = -errno;
            goto returnHandler;
        }
        break;
    default: //parent
            /*After this call 'nStatus' is an encoded exit value. WIF macros will extract how it exited*/
            if( waitpid(pid, &nStatus, 0) < 0 ) 
            {
                nRet = -errno;
                *pnChildExitStatus = errno;
            }
            if(WIFEXITED(nStatus))
            {
                nRet = EXIT_SUCCESS;
                *pnChildExitStatus = WEXITSTATUS(nStatus);
            }
            goto returnHandler;
        break;
}
returnHandler:
    return nRet;
}
```

My problem is as follows:

In some cases, Parent receives WEXITSTATUS(nStatus) != 0, although my child process always return 0 (I verified it with debug prints).

Can someone offer any idea on how is this possible?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `if (waitpid) ... if (WIF)...` is logically broken, missing else?

Comment: Waitpid is missing else, but it covers all logical options - meaning for any other return value other then 0, we should handle as error, otherwise - continue.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `waitpid()` is flawed.

If `waitpid()` is interrupted it will return -1,
however the value in `nStatus` may be undefined, 
thus `if (WIFEXITED(nStatus))` could still be true
and `WEXITSTATUS(nStatus)` could be anything.

What can interrupt a syscall, (like waitpid)?
A signal, like, SIGCHLD, for an exiting child.

The normal pattern is something like:

```
while ((wpid = waitpid(pid, &nStatus, 0)) != pid) {
    if (wpid == -1) {                    /* see below */
        if (errno == EINTR) continue;
        /* else handle the other error (pretty unlikely) */
        /* probably by returning something */
    }
}
if (wpid == -1) { /* error */ }    /* if you choose to `break' from the loop on error */
else { /* process exited */ }      /* you need to check the situation here */
```

The `if (wpid == -1)` is a bit superfluous here, as the only value `wpid` could have inside this loop is `-1`, but other variants of this pattern do not constrain `wpid` so tightly, so it's defensive programming against a change.

Similarly with `if (errno == EINTR)` as the only 3 `errno`s from most (all?) `waitpid`s are: EINTR, ECHILD (no children), and EFAULT (you got the 2nd arg wrong).  But, again, defensive programming.

Comment: So, are you implying that `WEXITSTATUS(0) == 1`?

Comment: On my systems, yes: `#define _WSTATUS(x)     (_W_INT(x) & 0177)`  `#define WIFEXITED(x)    (_WSTATUS(x) == 0)`

Comment: That's `WIFEXITED`, not `WEXITSTATUS`.

Comment: It is `WIFEXITED` that the original poster is checking after `wait`

Comment: Yes, but then they see `WEXITSTATUS` return 1 (according to the title, and body text)

Comment: In any event, depending on any specific encoding is bad practice -- that's why the various macro's exist.

Comment: I agree with not relying on encodings, and checking for `EINTR`, but I still don't see how `WEXITSTATUS` returns 1 when `nStatus` is 0.

Comment: On a "normal" implementation

Comment: It could be anything.  The standard says "[EINTR] The function was interrupted by a signal. The value of the location pointed to by stat_loc is undefined."

Comment: What happened for me, as it turns out, is one of an infinite number of outcomes allowed by the standard.